# Pop up message in Django

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, popup

I have a form in Django where I upload many files and then perform some data processing on those files. I want to display a loader message while it's still processing in the backend.
I know we can use messages in django but it only shows after the processing is complete, I want to display a little animation while data is being processed. I didn't use ajax to post the form since it was easier with the simple method.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):

    file_A = forms.FileField(label= "Upload File-A ")
    file_B = forms.FileField(label= "Upload File-B ")
    year = forms.IntegerField()
```

Views.py

```
def display_uploadpage(request):
       
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BudgetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_A = form.cleaned_data["file_A"]
            file_B = form.cleaned_data["file_B"]
            year = form.cleaned_data["year"]

            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            file_A_name = fs.save(file_A.name, file_A)
            file_B_name = fs.save(file_B.name, file_B)
            
            p = ProcessData(year, file_A,file_A_name,  file_B, file_B_name)
             msg = p.process()  

            messages.info(request, msg )  
                   
            return render(request, 'website/upload.html')
                        
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'website/upload.html', context)
```

upload.html

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!-- form method -->
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}              
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="upload">Upload</button> 
 </form>
```

**I wanted to add [this](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/HhdrA) animation in the page while it's still processing.**

Comment: where is your ajax call?

Comment: check https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: @iklinac I didn't add any